# Some type of counter in "for" loops in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm writing a program in Java for Spark 1.6.0 (so, please, don't supply Scala or Python code in your answers), and this is the code I'd like to implement:

```
double i = 0d;
JavaRDD<Vector> ideas = objects.map(
        new Function<BSONObject, Vector>()
        {
            @Override public Vector call(final BSONObject t) throws Exception
            {
                double[] xy = new double[2];
                xy[0] = i++;
                xy[1] = ((Long)((Date)t.get("date")).toInstant().toEpochMilli()).doubleValue();
                return Vectors.dense(xy);                    
            }
        }
);
```

but NetBeans shows an error: "Local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final".

I also tried to use Spark Accumulators, but if I call the value() method from the call() method I'm defining, a SparkException is raised during the job, telling me that "Task is not serializable", then the job fails.

So, how can I achieve my goal?

I apologize in advance if my English is not perfect (it's not my native language), and if my question could appear noob-ish, but I can't find any solution online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if it compiled it wouldn't work as you expect. Each executor get its own copy of the variables referenced inside closure and any modifications are strictly local and are not propagated back to original source. Spark supports writable [accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators-a-nameaccumlinka) which can be used as follows:

```
Accumulator<Double> accum = sc.accumulator(0d);

objects.map(
  ...
  accum.add(1d)
  ...
)
```

but these provide very weak guarantees (called at-least-once) when used inside transformations and, as you've already realized, are write-only from the worker perspective.

Regarding your code it looks like all you need is [`zipWithIndex`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#zipWithIndex%28%29):

```
objects.zipWithIndex().map(...)
```

Comment: You saved my day, and also my thesis. Thank you!